# Sencha touch: Are events not propagated down?

Tags: sencha-touch

Noob question.

I have an `activate` handler in a child `List`, but it doesn't fire. The `activate` event on the parent `Panel` does fire. I tried several other events, and  none of them propagate down down the hierarchy. Is this really the intended behavior? If so, how can I ensure that nested  widgets initialize properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if its intended behavior but you could add activate listeners on all members of the hierarchy and iterate through the child elements to initialize.

Comment: You mean handle the activate event at the parent level, and then manually call `fireEvent('activate', ...)` on each child?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing:
    this.on('activate', function () { this.query('childCmp')[0].fireEvent('activate'); }, this);

Answer (score 0):

The intended events surely fire for each of the components. For your case, are you adding the activate event in controller? Check if your reference is proper or put that listener in the list component itself and test.

Comment: They fire, but only for the top-level components. The activate handler is defined inside the child component itself. Exactly the same code is used in both the parent and child components, but only the parent handler is ever called.